# kohana prepared statement error

Tags: php, prepared-statement, kohana, kohana-3

When I use Kohana database query class with prepared statement, I'm getting an error: 
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Cannot use object of type Database_Query_Builder_Select as array

```
$query = DB::select('id,lat,lng')->from('projects')->where('id', '=', ':id');
$query->param(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
return $query[0];
```

With chaining it works fine:

```
$query = DB::select('id,lat,lng')->from('projects')->where('id', '=', ':id')->param(':id', $id)->execute();
return $query[0];
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not doing the same. In the second code, you assign the return value and access that, not the query. So something like this should work

```
$query = DB::select('id,lat,lng')->from('projects')->where('id', '=', ':id');
$query->param(':id', $id);
$result = $query->execute();
return $result[0];
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you are using a recent version of PHP (don't know which one for sure, think about 5.3) you could also do something like `return $query->execute()[0]`